# How can I make batching work with async dispatch calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Since React 18, state updates are [automatically batched](https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide#automatic-batching). When using Redux, [batches](https://react-redux.js.org/api/batch) are also used. However, it doesn't seem to work when using async dispatch calls. For example, for the thunk:

```
const incrementAsync = createAsyncThunk("incrementAsync", (_, { dispatch }) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    dispatch(increment());
  }, 1000);
});
```

The following will make the component rerender three times (but visually the counter only changes once):

```
const increment = () => {
  dispatch(incrementAsync());
  dispatch(incrementAsync());
  dispatch(incrementAsync());
};
```

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-ramanujan-w22z48?file=/src/features/counter/Counter.js)

I don't know if it is the expected behavior, but **how can I do so these updates are batched?** I would like my component to rerender only once, regardless of the number of updates.

---

**Please note:**
I only made these snippets for the question, my code has nothing to do with simple counters and **I need** the calls to be async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*@reduxjs/toolkit: ^1.9.5*

You can use [`autoBatchEnhancer`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/autoBatchEnhancer)

> A Redux store enhancer that looks for one or more "low-priority" dispatched actions in a row, and queues a callback to run subscriber notifications on a delay. It then notifies subscribers either when the queued callback runs, or when the next "normal-priority" action is dispatched, whichever is first.

`counterSlice.js`:

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk, prepareAutoBatched, SHOULD_AUTOBATCH } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const incrementAsync = createAsyncThunk('incrementAsync', (_, { dispatch }) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(increment());
    }, 1000);
});

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'counter',
    initialState: {
        value: 0,
    },
    reducers: {
        increment: {
            reducer: (state, action) => {
                console.log('action: ', action);
                state.value += 1;
            },
            prepare: prepareAutoBatched(),
        },
    }
});

export const { increment } = counterSlice.actions;

export const selectCount = (state) => state.counter.value;

export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

`store.js`:

```js
import { configureStore, autoBatchEnhancer } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import counterReducer from '../features/counter/counterSlice';

export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        counter: counterReducer,
    },
    enhancers: (existingEnhancers) => {
        // Add the autobatch enhancer to the store setup
        return existingEnhancers.concat(autoBatchEnhancer());
    },
});
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76751763-f2dxgl?file=/src/features/counter/counterSlice.js)

Comment: It seems to work! But I have two questions: will it work correctly if my thunk dispatches multiple actions in a specific order (I await them)? And can I use this if I don't have `createSlice` and only `builder.addCase`? I can edit my question to add more details on my true config if required.

Comment: Here is the answers to my own questions: yes it works correctly if I dispatch multiple actions in a specific order. And yes, I can use this even without `createSlice`. To do so I have to add `[SHOULD_AUTOBATCH] = true` to the meta data of my actions. For a `createAction`, it goes into the [`prepare`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction#using-prepare-callbacks-to-customize-action-contents) callback. For `createAsyncThunk`, it has to be set in both the `fullfiled` (using`fulfillWithValue`) and `pending` state (third parameter, `options.getPendingMeta`).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me out in the right direction! It's worth adding that [`autoBatchEnhancer` will be added by default on RTK v2.0.0](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/discussions/3449).

Answer (score 0):

To complete/update [@Lin Du's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76752262/9718056)...

For Redux Toolkit **2.0**, [`configureStore` now adds `autoBatchEnhancer` by default](https://redux.js.org/usage/migrations/migrating-rtk-2#configurestore-adds-autobatchenhancer-by-default), so it's no longer needed to add it to the enhancers. Here is how to use this feature without [`createSlice()`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice):

**For [`createAction()`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction), using a [prepare](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction#using-prepare-callbacks-to-customize-action-contents) callback (custom or [`prepareAutoBatched`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/autoBatchEnhancer#prepareautobatched))**

```js
import { SHOULD_AUTOBATCH, createAction, prepareAutoBatched } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const myAction = createAction("MY_ACTION", prepareAutoBatched);

// Same as:

export const myAction = createAction("MY_ACTION", (payload) => ({
  payload,
  meta: { [SHOULD_AUTOBATCH]: true }
}));
```

**For [`createAsyncThunk()`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk), using [`fulfillWithValue`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator) and [`option.getPendingMeta`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#options)**

```js
import { SHOULD_AUTOBATCH, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const myAction = createAsyncThunk(
  "MY_ACTION",
  async (payload, { fulfillWithValue }) => (
    fulfillWithValue(payload, { [SHOULD_AUTOBATCH]: true });
  ),
  { getPendingMeta: () => ({ [SHOULD_AUTOBATCH]: true }) }
);
```